# What is the logic here for post increment?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &x;
    *ptr = 0;
    printf("x= %d\n", x);
    printf("*ptr= %d\n", *ptr);

    *ptr += 5;
    printf("x= %d\n", x);
    printf("*ptr= %d\n", *ptr);
 
    (*ptr)++;
    printf("x= %d\n", x);
    printf("*ptr= %d\n", *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Acc. to precedence brackets will be first simplified and then `++` and therefore it will be post increment  :
`(*ptr)++` (third portion of question)

value should be 5 as it is post increment operator i.e it will first assign the value and then increment..In this case also it should first assign value and then  increment..But answer coming is
`6`

Comment: Post-increment refers to the value returned by the `++` expression. After `(*ptr)++` has executed, the value is incremented. To see the difference betweent post and pre increment you should do something like `printf(" ptr = %d\n", (*ptr)++)`

Comment: The increment instruction has been already executed

Comment: Note: when operator precedence is clear, as in this case, it doesn't matter in the slightest if you use post-increment or pre-increment. Which one of those to use only matters when the result of increment is used together with other operands in the same expression (which is also very bad practice, for numerous reasons). So if you had written `++(*ptr)` or even `++*ptr` you would get the same result still. Whereas `*ptr++` or `*++ptr` would have been wrong, since they would have incremented the pointer, not the pointed-at value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(*ptr)++; // increment the value (to 6)
// other stuff
printf( .... // print the value
```

The (post)-increment occurs substantially before the value is fetched to be printed.

Comment: so if we are pritning the value for first time it should be 5 and if pritning second time it should be 6 as it is (post) increment .. Right !!

Comment: @Theprofessor no the increment happens at `;`. It does not wait till next use of the pointer.

Comment: @Theprofessor The code has 3 pairs of print statements. First pair both print 0, second pair both print 5, third pair both print 6... The "post increment" that you are thinking about corresponds to the two assignment statements also present. There's no "delay" between the increment to allow the value 5 to be printed by the last pair of print statements. Things happen when they happen...

Answer (score 2):

```
int *ptr;
```

1. `(*ptr)++;`  increases the value of the object ***referenced*** by the pointer. The result is the same as `*ptr += 1;`
2. `*ptr++;` increases pointer itself. The result is the same as `ptr += 1;`

> value should be 5 as it is post increment operator i.e it will first
> assign the value and then increment.

No, the sequence point, in this case, is the semicolon. So this line simple increases the object referenced by the `ptr`.

To see what you want you need to use the post-increment operator directly in the more complex expression, loop or function call.

```
printf("*ptr= %d\n",(*ptr)++);
printf("*ptr= %d\n",x);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer..But unable to get through it..Can u please elaborate

Comment: UV for supplying the term "sequence point"... Thanks... `:-)`